# why is cloud function is throwing error everytime

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I am creating a simple cloud function that execute a simple python code from google source code repo.

The cloud function is not creating and throwing below error message each time:

the cloud function is not deploying. it is always failing with below message:

buildpackId buildpackVersion totalDurationMs userDurationMs

google.utils.archive-source 0.0.1 45 44

google.python.functions-framework-compat 0.9.2 0 0

google.python.functions-framework 0.9.5 65 65

google.python.pip 0.9.2 27642 27559

google.utils.label 0.0.1 0 0

Please help debug

Comment: Press [edit] and add the code of the function you're using.

Comment: Can you share your code and more logs?